# Preposition in "as there was no bus to travel BY/ON so I decided to ..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> As there was no bus to travel by/on so I decided to book a cab

Here bus refers to a means of transport if I am thinking right. But the answer given is "on"

Answer (score 1):

You can travel **by bus**, but you travel **on a bus**. So if there was no bus to travel on, you couldn't travel by bus. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would be considered wrong when choosing "by." I can only assume there is some missing information to the question that determines which preposition to use.
Here are the differences between using the two words.

"Travel by" refers to the means of transportation that you are using. In other words, what mode of transportation that you have decided to use, car, bus, train, etc.

By:

> Through the action or presence of

"Travel on" refers to the literal action of being on the bus.

On:

> In the state of being active, functioning or operating.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possible things that prevented your bus journey.

If there were no bus service designated for that route on that particular day then there would be ***no bus to travel by***. Or as some might say ***no bus by which to travel***.

But if a particular bus had had engine trouble or been taken out of service, so in theory the route still existed, but for want of a bus, there would be ***no bus to travel on***. OR - ***no bus on which to travel***.